# Getting thumbnail of a video picked from photos library

Tags: ios, video, thumbnails

I know this question has been asked many times on stackoverflow. But my problem is different. 
I am iterating on the albumns of photos library to get all videos and their thumbnails.
Now, the problem is, my code is very slow to get the thumbnail of each video. For example, there is 14 videos in my camera roll and the total time taken to generate the thumbnail is around 3-4 seconds. I am using this code.

```
+(UIImage*)imageFromVideoAtURL:(NSURL*)contentURL {
   UIImage* theImage = nil;
   AVURLAsset* asset = [[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:contentURL options:nil];
   AVAssetImageGenerator* generator = [[AVAssetImageGenerator alloc] initWithAsset:asset];
   generator.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = YES;
   NSError* err = NULL;
   CMTime time = CMTimeMake(1, 60);
   CGImageRef imgRef = [generator copyCGImageAtTime:time actualTime:NULL error:&err];

   theImage = [[[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:imgRef] autorelease];

   CGImageRelease(imgRef);
   [asset release];
   [generator release];

   return theImage;
}
```

I am finding a way to get the thumbnail of all videos very fast so that user has not to wait. I have seen apps on Apple store that are doing the same thing in just micro seconds. Please help.

I have also tried this code to generate the thumbnail, it is also very slow.

```
    MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:mediaUrl];
    moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = NO;
    UIImage *thumbnail = [[moviePlayer thumbnailImageAtTime:0.0 timeOption:MPMovieTimeOptionNearestKeyFrame] retain];
    [imageView setImage:thumbnail];  //imageView is a UIImageView
```

Comment: As you are using videos from image library, have you tried using `thumbnail` method of `ALAssetRepresentation` class?

Comment: I guess there is no method `thumbnail` in `ALAssetRepresentation`. and yes, I am using videos from image library.

Comment: I'm really sorry that I misquoted the class name. It should have been `ALAsset` instead. And it contains `thumbnail` as well as `aspectRatioThumbnail` methods.

Comment: Thanks, @AyanSengupta, I have found this in `ALAsset' class. Will try it. Could you please add this as answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are loading videos from image library, it should already have the embedded thumbnail of the video. This can be accessed using `thumbnail` or `aspectRatioThumnail` methods of `ALAsset` class.

So in your case the thumbnails could be loaded like:

```
ALAssetLibrary* lib = [ALAssetLibrary new];
[lib assetForURL:contentURL resultBlock:^(ALAsset* asset) {
    CGImageRef thumb = [asset thumbnail];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        //do any UI operation here with thumb
    });
}];
```

Please make sure to make any UIKit call in the main queue as `assetForURL::` method may invoke the `resultBlock` in some background thread.

Comment: Since ALAssetLibrary is deprecated from iOS9.0, how can we get the thumbnail from PHAsset of a video.

Comment: @UtsavDusad You need to use `[PHImageManager defaultManager] requestImageForAsset:...`. But the answer is beyond the scope of this question. So please create a separate question to know the exact process, if you haven't already solved it.

Comment: Please do not add "hope it helps" to your posts. This is a rhetorical device that attempts to curry favour with the question author (or subsequent reader) in an effort to beg for votes. It's not appropriate for technical writing - everyone just assumes that everyone else is trying to be helpful. Thanks!